# How to parse strings using streams or other better way?

Tags: java, regex, java-stream

I have a HashMap and I want to convert data in it to a Response object. Is it possible to achieve the code below that parses the string in a better and optimized and cleaner way? May be using streams?

```
class Converter{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String, Long>();
      map.put("111", 80) // first 
      map.put("1A9-ppp", 190) // second
      map.put("98U-6765", 900) // third
      map.put("999-aa-local", 95) // fourth

      List<FinalProduct> products = new ArrayList<>();
      for(String key : map.keySet()){
        FinalProduct response = new FinalProduct();
        String[] str  = key.split("\\-");
        response.id = str[0] //id is always present in key i.e 111, 1A9, 98U,999
        if(str.length == 2) {
             if(str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");){ // check if is numeric
                  response.code = str[1]; // 6765
             }
             else{
                  response.city = str[1]; //ppp
             }
        }
         if(str.length == 3){
                  response.client = str[1]; //aa
                  response.type = str[2];   // local
         } 
        response.qty = map.get[key];
        products.add(response);
      }
   }
}


class FinalProduct{

String id;
String city;
Long code;
String client;
String type;
Long qty;
// getters and setters
```

Comment: If your code works but you are looking for possible *improvements* then your question is better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There is many mistakes this code can't compile, missing ';', and other stuf

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

To make your code reusable, I'd suggest to create a `FinalProduct` constructor as

```
FinalProduct(String key, Long value) {
    String[] str = key.split("-");
    this.id = str[0];
    if (str.length == 2) {
        if (str[1].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
            this.code = Long.parseLong(str[1]);
        } else {
            this.city = str[1];
        }
    } else if (str.length == 3) {     // ELSE IF !!
        this.client = str[1];
        this.type = str[2];
    }
    this.qty = value;
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
List<FinalProduct> products = map.entrySet().stream()
                                 .map(e -> new FinalProduct(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It's definitely good design, to extract the key parsing into a constructor or , even a factory method.